# DEVELOPER_ERROR android production with @react-native-google-signin/google-signin WITHOUT FIREBASE

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo, google-signin

i have a problem with google login ONLY in Production/Android.
i use EXPO

i use @react-native-google-signin/google-signin dependency to add signin with google WITHOUT FIREBASE.

i receive in production/android "DEVELOPER_ERROR" error.

Into documentation i see that is always as misconfigured, but the only configuration we have is a fingerprint to add in Google Api Console.

i can't understand which fingerprint add for production.

FINGERPRINT on my google play console
[image]

FINGERPRINT found in android studio with command gradle signinreport
[image]

FINGERPRINT found with eas credentials
[image]
i try every fingerprint with the same result.

thanks in advanced

A help to workaround this problem